# How to validate email address

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I try this example but it have some email type not check.

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex =
@"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
@"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
@"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
@"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
@"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
@"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
@"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

This example does not check the email address which have type like email@domain.c-om,email@domain.c#omc ,email@11.160.58.260 , em#il@domain.com . What is correct way to check email address avoid that type?

Comment: first make a proper list of email addresses that you want to be checked. Then write a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you got the regex from? Looks like you got it from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html where it says

> You can (but you shouldn't--read on) implement it with this regular
>   expression

then it says

> The reason you shouldn't use this regex is that it only checks the
>   basic syntax of email addresses. john@aol.com.nospam would be
>   considered a valid email address according to RFC 5322.

Then that page suggests to use

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

For the Objective-C you have to escape the backslashes and you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

Categories Add Methods **isEmail**

```
 -(BOOL)isEmail {
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.  [A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z‌​]{2,4})$";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:self];
}
```

call this method

```
if([text isEmail]){
//validate email id
}else{
//not email id
}
```

[Disscusion for Email Validation](http://blog.logichigh.com/2010/09/02/validating-an-e-mail-address/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)candidate
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: Limiting TLDs to 4 letter is very poor, see: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to validate given string is email or not.

```
- (BOOL)validEmail:(NSString *) emailString
{
    if([emailString length]==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *regExPattern = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:emailString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [emailString length])];

    if (regExMatches == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Limiting TLDs to 4 letter is very poor, see: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 0):

+(BOOL)validEmailid:(NSString *)emailId{

```
 @try

  {

   BOOL stricterFilter = NO;

    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";

    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;

    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailId]){
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        [self showalertwithmessage:@"Invalid emailid"];

        return NO;
    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"Error occurred in in Utils::stringIsValidEmail : %@",[exception description]);
}
```

}